# Office Web Add-Ins: How to add "Install Outlook Add-In" button on the website (similar like FindTime does)

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-addins, office-js

I am developing a new Add-In for Outlook using Outlook JavaScript API. We have developed a first beta version and created a promo website to promote it. Here it is: https://molecula.email

Now I would like to add an option to install our add-in right from our website. I found this cool new add-in called [FindTime](https://findtime.microsoft.com/) which does exactly what I need. They have "Install for Free" button right on the landing page. If I click on the button it would redirect me to the MS login page and if I enter correct Office365 credential it redirects me back on the landing page and the add-in is automatically installed right in me Office365 profile. Next time you open Outlook the add-in already there.

The problem is FindTime developed by Microsoft internally and I am not sure whether they use some internal API to do that.

Is it possible to provide the same kind of UX for our promo website?

Comment: Hi Peter, did you successfully use one of the proposed solutions?

Comment: Hi Benoit, not yet, but I am going to try the idea proposed by Jason Johnston and will post the results here. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the EWS [InstallApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj219977(v=exchg.150).aspx) method to upload a base 64-encoded manifest.

Comment: Looks much more simple than my solution that uses Powershell!

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented an OAUTH flow where your server makes the requests to the Office365 apis, then on your server you have an oauth token.

Server side, you can use this token to start a [remote powershell session to add the add-in in the authenticated user mailbox](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/testing-and-tips?product=outlook). Of course, this would be easier if you are using a .NET backend because you can use such a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) to manage powershell execution scripts from pure .NET code.

I have not tested it but this is how I would tackle the problem. But I am not sure I would like people to install the add-in directly from my website rather than from the Office Store. Indeed, you will lower your download rates in the Office Store. I do not know how to handle manifest updates either...

We are also outlook add-in developers, have a look at our add-in [Keluro](https://keluro.com/).

Comment: Have you tried OAUTH with InstallApp..
I keep getting an error...
"The access token is acquired using an authentication method that is too weak to allow access for this application. Presented auth strength was 1, required is 2.";error_category="insufficient_auth_strength"